# mat-filtering/mat-sort not work correctly when use ngif in mat-table parent

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

Note that paging/sort not work correctly. Paging does not show the number of elements it is showing and sorting does not work, but if you delete the line in the html file ***ngIf="dataSource?.filteredData.length > 0"** the error is fixed.
If you use filtering, it works, but it does not show the filter amount

Check the example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqkekh-nm3pn2?file=app/table-pagination-example.html

Comment: do you want to have that *ngIf condition?

Comment: @yer hi!, Yes, I need it to hide the table when there are no results and show another message

Comment: you can use this *ngIf="dataSource?.filteredData" instead.

Comment: @yer Works! but not quite correctly. I updated the example with another link

Comment: could you tell what is not working correctly now?

Comment: @yer If you use the filter, when there are no matches, a message appears correctly, but the table does not disappear

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your component.ts, replace this code

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

with this :

```
  private paginator: MatPaginator;
  private sort: MatSort;


  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

And in your html:

```
    <mat-card *ngIf="!dataSource?.filteredData.length" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        <div><span>ZERO RESULT</span></div>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card *ngIf="dataSource?.filteredData.length">
    ** insert the table code that you have **
    </mat-card>
```

Comment: In Angular 9+, 

`@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;` and keep the ngAfterViewInit as same as in the answer.

Comment: Can anyone explain why it has to be done this way when using `mat-table` with `*ngIf` rather than what was already there in the component?

Comment: Thanks for this Answer. this worked for me in mat-table. I just voted

Comment: { static: false } is the default for Angular 9+ so you don't have to set it.

Answer (score 18):

This can be solved by the following strategy:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) set content(sort: MatSort) {
  this.dataSource.sort = sort;
}
```

Now even if you use *ngIf, it will work.

Comment: For anyone looking for more explanation, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359612/8437694) helps a bit; the `{ static: false }` option is for Angular 8+

Comment: Best answer, still working with Angular 13

Comment: { static: false } is the default for Angular 9+ so you don't have to set it.

Comment: I'm in Angular 15.  Don't think it worked for me:(

Answer (score 2):

Just adding static:false instead true, working fine
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false})e }) public sortaddEpisode: MatSort;

Comment: It worked just by adding static: false.

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) matSort: MatSort;

Answer (score 1):

I have faced issue in hiding mat-paginator using *ngIf so I fixed it using below workaround. Define the below style in `global.scss` and apply the this style conditionally in mat-paginator

```
.hide-paginator {
  display: none !important;
}

<mat-paginator 
[length]="totalElements"
      [pageSize]="searchDefinition.size" [pageSizeOptions]="paginationOptions" 
      [ngClass]="{'hide-paginator': data.length <= 0 }">
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Very smart. Thank you so much.  saved my life.  I can't figure out how to make the static thing work in all the other answers.  But this works like a charm modified for my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a table using ngIf. Using a setter on the ViewChild fixed the issue for the initial load but in my case when I would rebind the table datasource later (such as after editing an entry in the table and wanting to refresh the table rows), the sorting stopped working again. The only solution I found was to NOT use a setter for the viewChild and use setTimeOut when binding the table's sort:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;

this.dataSourceFaxes = new MatTableDataSource<ISuretyFaxModel>(this.suretyModel.SuretyFaxes);
setTimeout(() => {
    this.dataSourceFaxes.sort = this.sort;
}, 500);
```

I feel it is kind of a hack but nothing else seemed to work. If I find another way I will update.

**Update**

I found another way. Instead of using an ngIf on the table, I can use ngStyle to hide it an avoid the whole situation:

```
[ngStyle]="dataSourceFaxes?.data?.length > 0 ? {'visibility': 'visible'} : {'visibility': 'hidden'}"
```

This way the table is in the DOM but does not render until the condition is true. Don't need setTimeOut or using a setter on the viewChild

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the answer given by [Rut Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935364/6618218). In case sorting needs to be done based on custom table columns.
`sortingDataAccessor` is custom function for different behavior. This function that is used to access the value of the column when sorting and user can select any property based on data structure to sort data based on that property. It is very handy in case of sorting based on nested properties

Secondly, `{ static: false }` (Angular < 9) version is important to be there to access ViewChild element inside conditional statements.

[Migration Guide](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration)
*Starting with version 9, the static flag will default to false. At that time, any {static: false} flags can be safely removed, and we will have a schematic that will update your code for you.*

```html
  <table matSort
         mat-table
        [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="'column1'">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{element.<property-name>}}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      
    </table>
```

```
 @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    if (!ms) {
      return;
    }
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item: <T>, property: string) => {
      switch (property) {
        case <Column_Name_1>:
          return item.<Property>;
        case <Column_Name_2>:
          return item.<Property>;
        default:
          return item[property];
      }
    };
    this.dataSource.sort = ms;
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Adding `<tr>` tag in your html code and adding `mat-sort-header="fieldname"` you can get resolved.