# Angular MATABLE not showing data

Tags: angular, typescript

[UI shows datasource.filtereddata but mat table is not getting populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAvUO.png)

**please see the screen shot in the link.**
Mat table is not showing the data,below are the html and typescript details.could some one look into it?
json with data is getting displayed on the screen when i do datasource.filterdata..but table is not getting mapped to data.Console also shows the data.
console.log(this.dataSource);
  console.log(customers)

Html

```
<mat-card *ngIf="!dataSource?.filteredData" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
    <div><span>ZERO RESULT</span></div>
</mat-card>

<mat-card *ngIf="dataSource?.filteredData">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort>

    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="user_PHONE_ID">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>phone Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.user_PHONE_ID}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone_TYPE_CD">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone type cd</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.phone_TYPE_CD}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="last_MODIFIED_TS">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>last MODIFIED TS</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.last_MODIFIED_TS}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone_NBR">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone nbr</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.phone_NBR}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="user_ID">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone type cd</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.user_ID}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="creation_TS">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>creation ts</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.creation_TS}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</mat-card>

   <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource?.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="5"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
```

Typescript

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { CustomerlistService } from './services/customerlist.service';
import { Customer } from './models/customer';

// const ELEMENT_DATA: Customer[] = [
//   {lastModifiedTs: "1",    phoneNbr: "1",    userPhoneId: "1",    phoneTypeCd: "1",    userId: "1",    creationTs: "1" },
//   {lastModifiedTs: "2",    phoneNbr: "12",    userPhoneId: "12",    phoneTypeCd: "12",    userId: "12",    creationTs: "12" },];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-list',
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements  OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

dataSource= new MatTableDataSource<Customer>();;
customer;

customers: Customer[];

/** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
displayedColumns: string[] = ['user_PHONE_ID', 'phone_TYPE_CD','last_MODIFIED_TS','phone_NBR','user_ID','creation_TS'];

constructor(private customerListService: CustomerlistService){}

ngOnInit() {
this.customerListService.getUserPhone()
.subscribe((customers : Customer[])=> {
  this.customers = customers;
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(customers)
  console.log(this.dataSource);
  console.log(customers);});  
}
}
```

**Interface**

```
export interface Customer {
    last_MODIFIED_TS: string;
    phone_NBR: string;
    user_PHONE_ID: string;
    phone_TYPE_CD: string;  
    user_ID: string;
    creation_TS: string;  
}
```

**service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Customer } from '../models/customer';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerlistService {

  private _customers: BehaviorSubject<Customer[]>;

  private dataStore : {
    customer : Customer[]
  }
  private userPhoneUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/v1/userphones/115451';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.dataStore = { customer: [] };
    this._customers = new BehaviorSubject<Customer[]>([]);
   }

   get customers(): Observable<Customer[]>{
     return this._customers.asObservable();
   }

  getUserPhone() {
    return this.http.get<Customer[]>(this.userPhoneUrl);

  } 


  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse){
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      errorMessage = 'An error occured: ${err.error.message}';
    } else {
      errorMessage = 'Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is:${err.message}';
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }                                          
}
```

Comment: your property names don't match with the received data. Either change your backend or cell templates : `{{row.userPhoneId}}` -> `{{row.user_PHONE_ID}}`

Comment: Yep - `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.creationTs}}</td>` this should actually be `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.creation_TS}}</td>` (and the other columns are incorrect as well). Also, your interface is incorrect as well.

Comment: I changed the interface and the html with correct property names but still its not showing the data.@eldar @tftd

Comment: Please provide the `full` example next time. You have an `ngIf` which means that the container is not initialized until the data is retrieved. [mat-filtering/mat-sort not work correctly when use ngif in mat-table parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767580/mat-filtering-mat-sort-not-work-correctly-when-use-ngif-in-mat-table-parent)

Comment: without ngif too its not displaying data.when i replace service call with static data it works and mattable gets populated.But with service call its not.Please look at the code and advice.I have updated the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

service should return an array of objects to map to MATTABLE datasource  correctly.

**Below json  was not mapped correctly to  mattable.**
{"user_PHONE_ID":115451,"phone_TYPE_CD":"DAY   ","phone_NBR":"1111111111","user_ID":115821,"creation_TS":"2011-04-20T15:53:32.313+0000","last_MODIFIED_TS":null}

**But this worked**
**[**{"user_PHONE_ID":115451,"phone_TYPE_CD":"DAY   ","phone_NBR":"1111111111","user_ID":115821,"creation_TS":"2011-04-20T15:53:32.313+0000","last_MODIFIED_TS":null}**]**